# Android: No Activity found to handle Intent (trying to add an activity to exsisting app)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Ok so I am very new to the Android programming, I am starting week 2 of this class and cannot for the life of me figure out what is going wrong. I have read/watched tons of tutorials on adding new Activities and nothing works.

Assignment: Use the Activities app and add a fourth activity

My activity is simple, 3 buttons and an image. One button makes the image visible and the other makes it invisible. Third returns back to the main.

Note: I edited the original app to have buttons on Main Activity because it had me hitting center on the d-pad which I found dumb. Another note is that Activity 2 & 3 use the same layout and do basically the same thing from what I can tell

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String tag = "Events";

int request_Code = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //---hides the title bar---
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.d(tag, "In the onCreate() event");

    Button act2Butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act2Butt);
    Button act3Butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act3Butt);
    Button act4Butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.act4Butt);

    act2Butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent("net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2"), request_Code);
        }
    });

    act3Butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent("net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2"), request_Code);
        }
    });

    act4Butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent("net.learn2develop.MYACTIVITY"), request_Code);
        }
    });
}
/*
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
    {
        //startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2"));    
        //startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(
            "net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2"), 
            request_Code);

    }
    return false;
}
*/

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == request_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {                
            Toast.makeText(this,data.getData().toString(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }            
    }
} 

public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStart() event");
}    
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onRestart() event");
}    
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onResume() event");
}
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onPause() event");
}    
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onStop() event");
}    
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "In the onDestroy() event");
}    

public class MyActivity extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity4);

    Button yesButt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
    Button noButt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noButton);
    Button finButt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finButton);
    final ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);


    yesButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    noButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    finButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.setData(Uri.parse("OMG IT WORKS"));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

            finish();
        }
    });
}

public class Activity2 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    String defaultName=""; 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras!=null)
    {
        defaultName = extras.getString("Name");        
    }
    //---get the EditText view--- 
    EditText txt_username = 
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);        
    txt_username.setHint(defaultName);

    //---get the OK button---
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_OK);

    //---event handler for the OK button---
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent data = new Intent();

            //---get the EditText view--- 
            EditText txt_username = 
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);

            //---set the data to pass back---
            data.setData(Uri.parse(
                txt_username.getText().toString()));                           
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

            //---closes the activity---
            finish(); 
        }
    });  
}
```

I have entered the code for Main Activity, My Activity (the one I made), and Activity 2. My Activity runs great and does exactly what I want it to but if I try to access it from main it dies.

> 928-928/net.learn2develop.Activities E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: net.learn2develop.Activities, PID: 928
>       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=net.learn2develop.MYACTIVITY }
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
>               at net.learn2develop.Activities.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

This code is for my last attempt and making it work before throwing my hands up. Last thing I did was make My Activity act like the other and use startActivityForResult.

Any help would help greatly. I don't know if it matters or not but I do not have a .class for My Activity in the bin directory but there is one for all the others.

If you need any more info please just ask.

Like I said before I'm really new to the whole Android area.

Edit: Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="My Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="net.learn2develop.MYACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Comment: Can you post your Manifest file?

Comment: I have added my manifest entry for my activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add the `Activity` to the manifest. If you are sure you have done this, I would recommend using an `Intent` slightly differently.

Try using an `Intent` the following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

The first parameter of this `Intent` is the current `Activity`. The second parameter is the`Activity` you wish to navigate to. Handling an `Intent` this way prevents a small typo in the package name which would throw that exception. As long as the `Activity` you are trying to navigate to is in the manifest and you have set up your `Intent` like the code above, everything should work fine.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: This worked like a charm thank you sooo much! Took me 3 hours till I posted and after that 17 mins and fixed

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your activity to your manifest

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MySecondActivity" 
    android:label="@string/title_second_activity">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
net.learn2develop.MYACTIVITY
```

Android is not finiding the above activity like other engineers said,add this activity in your manifest file so JVM can find which class you are referring to.